# Spectral Graph Convolutions: What are the spectral filters functions

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis, graph-neural-network

I am trying to understand the mathematical meaning of one of the steps that appear in the **Convolution Theorem** (Step 4 [here](https://atcold.github.io/pytorch-Deep-Learning/en/week13/13-1/)).

To give some context, this is related to applying the **convolution theorem with Graphs**. For that it uses the **Eigen Decomposition** of the **normalized Laplacian Matrix** from which the **Fourier Functions / Fourier Transform** appear as the EigenVectors of this Matrix.

So elaborating all the concepts and giving context:

**Graph Laplacian $\Delta$**

$$ \begin{aligned} & \mathcal{G}=(V, E, A)  \rightarrow \underset{n \times n}{\Delta}=\mathrm{I}-D^{-1 / 2} A D^{-1 / 2}  \\ 
& \text { where } \\ 
& \quad \quad \underset{n \times n} D=\operatorname{diag}  (\sum_{j \neq i} A_{i j}) \\
& \quad \quad A \equiv \text adjacency \quad Matrix
\end{aligned} $$

Note: This is called the **normalized Laplacian** Matrix

**Fourier Functions**

The following is the eigen-decomposition of graph Laplacian,

$$ \underset{n \times n}{\Delta}=\Phi^{T} \Lambda \Phi $$

$\Phi$ contains the Lap eigenvectors $\phi_1$ to $\phi_n$, each of size $n \times 1$, and those are also called **Fourier functions** that form an orthonormal basis ($\Delta$ is positive semi-definite matrix) so  $\begin{array}{ll} \underset{n \times 1}{\Delta \phi_{k}}=\lambda_{k} \phi_{k}, & k=1, \ldots, n \ & \end{array}$.

Then my understanding is that $\phi_i$ **is a vector and not a function** (this is relevant for the question below)

**Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform**

The Fourier transform is basically projecting a function h on the Fourier functions, and the result are the coefficients of the Fourier series

Fourier Transform/ coefficients of Fourier Series

$$ \underset{n \times 1}{\mathcal{F}(h)} =\Phi^{T} h \ =\hat{h} $$

Inverse Fourier Transform

$$ \underset{n \times 1}{\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{h})} =\Phi \hat{h} = \Phi \Phi^{T} h=h $$

**Convolution Theorem**

Fourier transform of the convolution of two functions is the pointwise product of their Fourier transforms. Below is stated the theorem where $\Phi^{T}w = \hat{w}$

$$ \begin{aligned} \underset{n \times 1} {w * h} &=\mathcal{F}^{-1} (\mathcal{F}(w) \odot \mathcal{F}(h))) \\ &=\underset{n \times n}{\Phi}\left( \underset{n \times 1}{\hat{w}}\odot \underset{n \times 1}{\Phi^{T} h}\right) \\ &=\Phi\left(\underset{n \times n}{\hat{w}(\Lambda)} \underset{n \times 1}{\Phi^{T} h}\right) \\ &=\Phi \hat{w}(\Lambda) \Phi^{T} h \\ &=\hat{w}(\Phi \Lambda \Phi^{T}) h \\ &=\underset{n \times n}{\hat{w}(\Delta)} \underset{n \times1}h \ & \end{aligned} $$

With all this context, now my question is **what is the $\hat{w}$ vector that is treated like a function?**

In the **third $=$** of the convolution theorem you can see that the pointwise multiplication has been replaced by a matrix multiplication converting $\hat{w}$ to $\hat{w}(\Lambda)$. This is understandable to me interpreting $\hat{w}$ as a function instead of a vector then each of the components of $\hat{w}$ correspond to evaluate the function on one of the **eigenvalues** $\lambda_i$, and **these are then only points you have of this function**:

$$    
\hat{w} = \begin{bmatrix}
           \hat{w}(\lambda_1) \\
           \hat{w}(\lambda_2) \\
           \vdots \\
           \hat{w}(\lambda_n)
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$

So it is understandable that:

$$
        \text Given \quad \Lambda =  \begin{bmatrix}
           \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\           
           0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
           \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
           0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \\
          \end{bmatrix} \implies  \hat{w}(\Lambda) =
          \begin{bmatrix}
           \hat{w}(\lambda_1) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\           
           0 & \hat{w}(\lambda_2) & \cdots & 0 \\
           \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
           0 & 0 & \cdots & \hat{w}(\lambda_n) \\
          \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is clear and makes sense because the vector $\hat{w}$ is by construction defined in the **eigenvalues**. But what about the **5th and 6th $=$**? How do you interpret $\hat{w}(\Phi \Lambda \Phi^{T})$ and $\hat{w}(\Delta)$?

There is also a great video on Youtube in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iiv9R6BjxHM&t=2985s where you can go over the explanation of this (but it does not explain what I am asking, Xavier just refers to it as the **spectral filter**) on the minute 40:13 and 46:52

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of sloppy / inconsistent / informal notation. $\hat w(\Lambda)$ is just the vector $\hat w$ rearranged into a diagonal matrix. Then you could say, "actually let's call the entire thing $\Phi \text{diag}(\hat w) \Phi^T$ just $\hat w(\Delta)$ for short. And then, because we want to make $\hat w(\Delta)$ some learnable function with a fixed number of parameters and a limited computational budget, let's actually define it as, for example, $\hat w(\Delta) = \theta_1 \Delta + \theta_2 \Delta^2$ (this is the "LapGCN" example from the next page of the linked article).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I thought at the beginning but then seeing the image 16 in webpage mentioned in the question (https://atcold.github.io/pytorch-Deep-Learning/en/week13/13-1/) and  also at 47:15 of the mentioned video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iiv9R6BjxHM&t=2985s) it is not that clear to me. It seems like there are continuous elements in the fourier functions that compose then continuous spectral filters.